# Getting 400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch when trying to grant permission to Gmail SMTP plugin

Tags: plugins, email, google, smtp

I am trying to add Google SMTP plugin to my wordpress website.

I have installed plugin, then went to Google Developer Console created new project, added Gmail API, added Credentials.

Now this step came out different to how I remember it used to be. Instead of getting API key I got a JSON file that has all the info, still fields seem to match mostly.

I then went to settings form in Gmail SMTP Plugin and mapped settings in following way:

`Client id` field to `client_id` from Json
`Client Secret` field to `private_key` from Json
`Client Email` field to `client_email` from Json

(see below)
[image]

When I try to Grant Permission I get

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request, `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=gmail-smtp-settings&action=oauth_grant`, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/113520075367233598862?project=[my_project_id]](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/113520075367233598862?project=%5Bmy_project_id%5D)

So I clicked the link and added `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=gmail-smtp-settings&action=oauth_grant` in google developer console, `OAuth Conscent Screen` tab `Homepage URL (Optional)` field and saved it but error remains my guess is ether I am not putting url into correct place or because I am running app from localhost.

**Where do I need to set up redirect url for this error to go away?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted out myself:

JSON file indeed was the issue
I went back to Google Developer Console and choose to `create Credentials` again it then gave me an option of `OAuth client Id` and later an option to add origin and redirect urls which sorted the issue.

[image]